# Python - re - need help for regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I've searched by myself, but can't manage to make a successful regular expression.

I have an html file containing variables between `[]` and I'd like to get every words inside these.

```
<div id='client_info'>
    <p><b>[client_name]</b><br/><b>[client_company]</b></p>
    <p>[client_address]<br/>[client_CP]<br/>[client_city]</p>
</div>
```

There it should give me an array containing "client_name", "client_company", "client_address", ...

I've did this :

```
vars = re.search('\[(.*)\]', html_template)
groups = vars.groups()
print groups
```

But it outputs `('client_name]</b><br/><b>[client_company',)`

I've tried playing with `^` and `$` but unsuccessfully.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look at this, you will understand: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html‎

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use a non-greedy quantifier, like this:

```
re.search('\[(.*?)\]', html_template)
```

Or a character class, like this:

```
re.search('\[([^\]]*)\]', html_template)
```

And use [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to get all matching sub strings.

Comment: This gives me only one result : `('client_name',)`

Comment: @Loïc use `re.findall()` in similar fashion

Answer (score 1):

Python has a very powerful library named [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup). I'd recommend you to use this for parsing html. So I'd recommend you to parse the `div` using this library first. And then perform regular expression.

```
html = '''
...some htmls...
<div id='client_info'>
    <p><b>[client_name]</b><br/><b>[client_company]</b></p>
    <p>[client_address]<br/>[client_CP]<br/>[client_city]</p>
</div>
...more htmls...
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
div = soup.find("div", {"id":"client_info"})
p = div.findAll("p")
for tag in p:
    print re.findall('\[([^\]]*)\]', tag.renderContents())
```

May be there is a way to parse the `<br/>` using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), but I don't know it.